# Get exact timezone of client in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to know exact timezone of the client regardless if it is falling under list of timezones having same GMT.

EX: [image]

Here if a user is from Cairo, how can I identify from javascript if he is from Cairo.There are too many countries which fall under same GMT.

I used this :

```
var timezone = new Date().toTimeString().split("(");
console.log( timezone[1].toString().replace(")", ""));
```

But this is always returning `Eastern Europe Standard Time`.

I am stuck, and I dont know how to achieve this.

Basically I have populated a dropdown with all Timezones from Server side, and I need to how can i select the timezone depending upon the users current timezone.

[image]

Comment: Best to check for API to figure out user's country from some browser JS api and use it to figure out the respective time zone

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Date object, try using the [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions) like this ([compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#search=Intl)):

```js
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```

Comment: ok, but how can I select the dropdown on basis of country.It is just returning Africa/Cairo

Comment: @Abhishek post your select html, you'll have to match the given timezone with the value of the select options

Comment: I am filling timezone dropdown with c# TimezoneInfo Class.And I am using angularjs, so it is not possible to post the code here or to remake the item.

Comment: However you can work, by changing the timezone of your machine and match the code